# Watch Service Java 7 polling loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I was a bit surprised that Watch Service should be implemented as a process/thread with a polling loop. I don't remember any other API in Java that is supposed to do it.

Wouldn't it be much better to implement it as a set of callbacks (listeners, observers, etc..)?

BTW - is there any third-party library that does pretty much the same, but using callbacks model?

Comment: I don't understand the problem here. Even with the callback model, you have to get the events from _somewhere_. Another thread, basically, which does the callback for you. You can consider a `WatchService` as a "callback caller"...

Comment: fge: If you look into the WatchService class hierarchy, you'll see that only the general PollingWatchService uses a naive busy mechanism under the hood. The other watch services rely on OS features that capture the events more efficiently - probably as efficient as waiting for bytes being sent to a stream. The way the watch service API is designed, that benefit is again taken away when the application tries to receive the events from the WatchKey, because there is no blocking waitForEvent() or similar. There is a huge difference between an idle and a busy background thread.

Comment: "EDIT": See my answer for a non-busy approach that works. Still, the way explained in The Java Tutorials http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html is a busy one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) has some file watching services which I think are much better than the ones in Java 7. Im not sure if they use callbacks, but they are much more intuitive in my opinion.

And yes, I think that an observer model would be much better. I read somewhere that its a bit tougher to do this with Java because it runs through a virtual machine, and to get listeners on files you need to talk directly to the OS. Im not sure of the details or validity of this though.

Comment: You're referring to http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/monitor/package-summary.html ? A runnable that spawns a monitoring thread triggering any registered FileAlterationObserver at a specified interval.

Answer (score 4):

I build on Alexeis answer, but I don't think he was clear enough... look at this example code:

```
WatchService service = dir.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
WatchKey key = dir.register(service, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_MODIFY, ENTRY_DELETE);
System.out.println(key);

for(;;) {
    WatchKey k = service.take();
    System.out.println(k);
    for(WatchEvent<?> ev:k.pollEvents()) {
        System.out.println(ev.kind());
        if(ev.kind() == OVERFLOW) continue;
        //TODO
        System.out.println(ev.context());
    }
    if(!k.reset()) break;
}

key.cancel();
```

If you check the `println(key)` / `println(k)` outputs, you'll see that the same object is returned over and over; `take()` returns every time that key is signalled, so to use multiple keys with the same `WatchService`, just check what key was returned every time. That also means that your loop blocks as long as the key was not signalled - exactly what you want.

the `if(!k.reset()) break;` is crucial too; this is what I forgot when writing my comment on Alexeis answer. My assumption was that `take()` is called by `register()`, and thus no key should be returned in my user code, because register() already consumed it. With that mis-assumption, I didn't recognize what was actually going on.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use polling, you can use WatchService.take(), which returns immediately when a change occur. Yes it requires a thread, but single thread can be used for multiple objects being watched. So it is easy to implement a singleton which owns a watching thread and allows to register callbacks for each object.

As for third party libraries, look at [Guava EventBus](http://codingjunkie.net/eventbus-watchservice/). I did not try it and am not sure if it fits your needs.

Comment: that's not what WatchService.take() does. It returns a WatchKey, not a WatchEvent. Funnily enough, in my test on Linux, after the first alteration I caused on the file system, it returned the same WatchKey as with Path.register(...) again.

Comment: "EDIT": I concede to you. See my answer for details.